# Object is given: let obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}; Convert the keys of this object in one array, and the values in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem with converting object keys and values in two separate arrays.

Please see my code below:

```
let obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5};
let arr1=[];
let arr2=[];
for( key in obj){
  for(let i=0; i<5;i++){
    arr1[i]=key
    arr2[i]=obj[key]
  }
}
 console.log(arr1)
 console.log(arr2)
```

I have wrong answer:
[ 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e' ] 
[ 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `Object.keys` and `Object.values`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

If you wanted to use your code:

```
let obj = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5};
let arr1=[];
let arr2=[];
for(let key in obj){
  arr1.push(key);
  arr2.push(obj[key]);
}
 console.log(arr1)
 console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: @LiudmilaKristinevich glad to help! Might be a good idea to mark one of the solutions as correct for other people if they come across this.

Comment: Done :) Thank you one more time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr1= Object.keys(obj)
let arr2= Object.values(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this an exercise for a class? There's built in Javascript methods for this exact thing. [Keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) & [Values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
let obj = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
  'd': 4,
  'e': 5
};
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```